# How can I add an additional field to the user object created at first sign in using Next Auth providers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm new to Next JS and this is my first time using Next Auth for authorization. I'm using the GitHub Provider and the Email Provider for authorization purpose in my app. For my app, I need the users to have a fullname and a username but I'm not able to figure out how to do it as I only get name and profile picture (from GitHub Provider, I get only email when using the Email Provider), and email. I want the user to be redirected to a page where they fill out a form with their fullname and a username, and only then I want the user object to be saved in the database. I'm using MongoDB here.